# Alternative to Pandas Group By to conditionally manipulate columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to use Pandas `Series.shift()` in order to manipulate pandas columns believing that it much faster than `Pandas.Groupby`. The reason I am looking for an alternative to pandas groupby is because my data has `~700K rows` and looping over each group to perform column manipulation is taking a lot of time. The snippet of the data is shown below. The function I have is as follows:

```
def func1(x):
    blck_list = [
               'b_9:00AM to 10:00AM',
               'c_10:00AM to 11:00AM',
               'd_11:00AM to 12:00PM'
         ]

    if x["Row_ID"].shift(-1) == x["Row_ID"]:
        for i in blck_list:
            if x[i] != 0:
                x[i] = x[i] - 1              
    return x

temp = func1(df)
```

The data is as follows:

```
df= 
Row_ID      b_9:00AM to 10:00AM  c_10:00AM to 11:00AM  d_11:00AM to 12:00PM  
1-1000156                 0                     0                     0  
1-1000156                 0                     0                     0  
1-1000156                 0                     0                     0  
1-1000CY4                 4                     0                     3  
1-1000CY4                 5                     0                     0  
1-1000CY4                 0                     1                     3  
1-1000CY4                 0                     2                     4  
1-1000GH4                 2                     1                     7 
1-1000GH4                 0                     2                     0  
1-1000K1A                 0                     0                     0  
1-1000OZ1                 1                     0                     0  
1-1000OZ1                 1                     0                     0  
1-10012IB                 0                     0                     0  
1-10012IB                 0                     0                     0  
1-10012IB                 0                     0                     0
```

All I want to do is subtract 1 from the columns for rows with similar `Row_ID` that is not `0`. My function produces following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

If I use `Pandas.apply()` method to call the i.e.`temp = df_pivot.apply(func1, axis=1)` I get following error:

> AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'shift'", 'occurred at
>   index 567517')

What is the correct way to use `Series.shift()` method here. Is there any other alternative way to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to do? "subtract 1 from the columns [which columns?] for rows with similar [what does similar mean?] Row_ID that is not - [what is not 0? the first character of rowID?]"